# How can I repair clicking sound when you try to turn the key?

Tags: engine, electrical, starting

I had a mechanic to fix a crankshaft position sensor on my car. He said in the process he took off the starter.

He said that the car would not start up, it's just making a clicking sound when he tried to start it up again. He said he took the starter off twice and had it tested. The starter is still good.

I had to have my car towed back to me. The starter is good. The battery is good. When you turn the key all it does is make a clicking sound.

I don't know what else to do but to junk my car. Is this an electrical problem? How can I repair this?

Comment: Surely, if the mechanic took the starter off, it is down to the mechanic to get it back on correctly.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What tests have been done to prove the battery is in good shape? Also, what is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question.

Comment: Why did you take the car to him in the first place? Was the check engine light on? Did it crank over but not start?

Comment: What make of car and year?

Answer (score 2):

1)If the starter is good, the battery is good and when you start the car, the crankshaft do turn over then there is something wrong with the crankshaft sensor.

2)The clicking sound when you start: It's either the battery doesn't have enough power delivery to the starter and/or the solenoid of the starter is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Double check the starter. If the carbon brushes are used up completely,then you'll need to replace them.

If the starter is good, then it's an electrical problem. You need to check all your fuses under the dashboard and under the hood.

Use a torch and shine the light over all the fuses. There must be one which is blown (wire is broken between connections). Replace that fuse with one having same rating otherwise this will result in the fuse being blown again,preventing the car from starting.

Finally,make sure that your mechanic connected all the wires including those which are linked to your alternator and to your starter.

Answer (score 0):

If your car is an older GM model (1960s - 1970s or so) there is a small solenoid (about the size of a soup can) on top of the starter; see the image after the topic "INSIDE THE STARTER" on http://www.aa1car.com/library/1999/cm119948.htm).

If you take that solenoid off (easy to do; remove the bolts holding it to the starter, give it a quarter turn, and pull it out) and disassemble it, there is a copper disk that is probably dirty.  If so, just use a wire brush or steel wool to clean it and reassemble.  I've fixed a few GM starters this way.

Comment: In what context is a solenoid the size of a soup can considered small? Nuclear submarine repair?

Comment: Okay, how about 4" long and 2.5" in diameter as a guess as the size of a GM starter solenoid.